# What would be the best way to take a string of html, chop it up, and put each piece into an array?

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays, text-processing

I have a general idea of how I can do this, but can't pinpoint how exactly to get it done. I am sure it can be done with a regex of some sort. Wondering if anyone here can point me in the right direction.

If I have a string of html such as this

```
some_html = '<div><b>This is some BOLD text</b></div>'
```

I want to to divide it into logical pieces, and then put those pieces into an array so I end with a result like this

```
html_array = ["<div>", "<b>", "This is some BOLD text", "</b>","</div>" ]
```

Comment: Is it always tag tag text tag tag?

Comment: no. I just used a simple example. The html is being stored in a db for a blog post. The blog post is being made with a rich text editor, so the html is just being generated depending on what the user inputs. I need to process the stored html so I can append it back into my rich text editor (contentEditable div) when the user wants to edit the post.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than use regex I'd use the [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html) gem (a gem for parsing html written by [Aaron Patterson](http://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri) - contributor to Rails and Ruby). Here's a sample of how to use it:

```
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<html><body><h1>Mr. Belvedere Fan Club</h1></body></html>")
```

You can then call `html_doc.children` to get a [nodeset](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html) and work your way from there

```
html_doc.children  # returns a nodeset
```

Comment: Cool. I will give it a try. Can you feed any html string in the Nokogiri::HTML method? Or does it have to be a whole html document?

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I am going to dig through the docs for a little bit and try this out.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @pguardiario you're right that I don't answer the question in the *title*. But the author's question states he's unsure of how to solve this problem and he's looking for help to point him in the *right* direction. That's what I tried to answer.

Comment: Hmm, nokogiri is the right tool for parsing html, but it won't help him split it.

Answer (score 4):

Use an HTML parser, for instance, [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/). Using SAX you can add tags/elements to the array as events are triggered.

It's [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) to try to regex HTML, unless you're planning to treat only a small determined subset of it.

Comment: I agree in general. But this seems straightforward enough to use regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
some_html.split(/(<[^>]*>)/).reject{|x| '' == x}
```